# For a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex, how do I add a new column that is an aggregation of the resampled DatetimeIndex?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I have a DataFrame with a DatetimeIndex, and I want to create a new column that is an aggregation of another column, aggregated by the Datetime at a slower frequency. For example, hourly values and the daily mean of the day they're a part of:

```
[index]                A   A_daily_mean
2018-08-01  00:00:00   6   7.5
2018-08-02  01:00:00   7   7.5
2018-08-03  02:00:00   8   7.5
2018-08-04  03:00:00   9   7.5
```

Is there a one-liner for this?

This is super easy for other groupby aggregations (on non-datetimes):

```
df['groupby_mean'] = df.groupby([col1, col2]).mean()
```

but grouping on the date of the DatetimeIndex fails miserably:

```
df['mean_of_resampled'] = df.groupby(df.index.date).mean()
```

or alternatively

```
df['mean_of_resampled'] = df.resample('1d').mean()
```

which both give:

```
[index]                A   A_daily_mean
2018-08-01  00:00:00   6   7.5
2018-08-01  01:00:00   7   NaN
2018-08-01  02:00:00   8   NaN
2018-08-01  03:00:00   9   NaN
```

I know I can add back the values by doing a merge or join, but I'm wondering if I'm missing some better, happier way.

Comment: Is your first `DateFrame` right? They are all different dates?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for `transform()`, e.g.:

```
In []:
df['A_daily_mean'] = df.groupby(df.index.date).transform('mean')
df

Out[]:
                     A  A_daily_mean
2018-08-01 00:00:00  6           7.5
2018-08-01 01:00:00  7           7.5
2018-08-01 02:00:00  8           7.5
2018-08-01 03:00:00  9           7.5
```